# useState value used setInterval is not updating in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to pass the value to `addEventListener(mousemove)` from `setInterval`. Somehow it's not working properly. Can someone help?

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  function refreshClock() {
    setDate(new Date());
  }

  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;

  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  
  let windowHeight = window.innerHeight/2;
  let windowWidth = window.innerWidth/2;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);  

    const onMouseMove = function(e) {
      x = e.clientX;
      y = e.clientY;

      if (x < windowWidth+100 && x > windowWidth-100 && y < windowHeight+100 && y > windowHeight-100 ) {
        setText(`${date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')}`);
      } else {
        setText('');
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <>
      {text}
    </>
  )
```

I'm trying to make time shows when the mouse is around the center of the window. setInterval is working fine without addEventListener.

Comment: I'd suggest learning javascript before using React The method 'setDate' is not passed into that method and does not exist so wouldn't do anything

Comment: @SteveTomlin Can you clarify your comment for the OP? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying. `setDate` exists and AFAICT doesn't need to be passed anywhere.

Comment: @DaveNewton The above has been updated. It didn't exist previously, and yes - it does need to be set. It is not a method existing on the window object. Maybe you are confusing it with the method that exists on the date object.

Comment: @SteveTomlin Hm, I don't see any change in the edit history, but ok. I still don't understand what you're saying--`setDate` is defined on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue you are having is that -

1. your `useEffect` runs only once
2. `onMouseMove` is declared inside the effect
3. `onMouseMove` closes over `date`
4. `date` will always be the same because the `onMouseMove` never gets an updated value
5. `setText` therefore will only display the first `date`

Another issue you are having is -

1. window width/height are computed once outside the effect
2. `onMouseMove` closes over these values
3. if the window is resized, the event listener will keep the old values

We can fix these issues by moving `onMouseMove` outside the effect. And instead of copying `date` state to `text`, we will use `useRef` to simply toggle the visibility on/off. In react this is known as keeping a [*single source of truth*](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned). Here's a minimal reproducible example -

```js
function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())
  const isDateVisible = React.useRef(false)
  
  const refreshClock = () =>
    setDate(new Date()) // update clock
    
  const onMouseMove = event => {
    const wx = window.innerWidth/2
    const wy = window.innerHeight/2
    const x = event.clientX
    const y = event.clientY
    isDateVisible.current = // update visibility
      x < wx+100 && x > wx-100 && y < wy+100 && y > wy-100
  }
  
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      const t = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000)
      addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(t)
        removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
      }
    },
    [] // refreshClock and onMouseMove have zero deps
  )
  
  return isDateVisible.current
    && date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
body::before { content: "move the cursor to the center"; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**strict dependencies**

In general, you will need to include any free variables as dependencies to your effects. If we were to be strict, `refreshClock` and `onMouseMove` would be listed as dependencies, but they have zero dependencies of their own and so it's safe to leave them out.

`refreshClock` and `onMouseMove` are recreated each time `date` state changes and the component is re-rendered. If we list them as dependencies to `useEffect` then the effect will re-run too, which we'd like to avoid.

Using `useCallback` ensures that `refreshClock` and `onMouseMove` will point to the same function object for each render, and prevents the effect from re-running unnecessarily. This updated program has the same behaviour as the one above, but it is more strict, and possibly communicates intentions more clearly.

```js
function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())
  const isDateVisible = React.useRef(false)
  
  const refreshClock = React.useCallback(
    () => setDate(new Date()),
    [] // zero dependencies
  )
    
  const onMouseMove = React.useCallback(
    event => {
      const wx = window.innerWidth/2
      const wy = window.innerHeight/2
      const x = event.clientX
      const y = event.clientY
      isDateVisible.current =
        x < wx+100 && x > wx-100 && y < wy+100 && y > wy-100
    },
    [] // zero dependencies
  )
  
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      const t = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000)
      addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(t)
        removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
      }
    },
    [refreshClock, onMouseMove] // strict dependencies
  )
  
  return isDateVisible.current
    && date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
body::before { content: "move the cursor to the center"; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Final notes:

1. Do not include state setter function as dependency. `setDate` is already guaranteed to be a non-changing value from `useState`
2. Do not include references as dependencies. Refs do not represent reactive state change and therefore do not trigger renders.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation!!!!! Helped me understanding issues a lot. Best wishes to you and hope you have a wonderful day!